# Xcode 5.1 Suppress Semantic Issue Warnings

Tags: xcode5, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

After updating my Xcode IDE to 5.1, I started to get some weird warnings from 3rd party libraries (Facebook-iOS SDK, RestKit etc.) in my application when compiling.

```
@property (copy, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *methodName;

No 'assign', 'retain' or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed.
Default property 'assign' is not appropriate for non-GC object.
```

[image]
How can I suppress those kind of warnings in Xcode?

Thanks.

Comment: Suppressing warnings is always the wrong approach. You need to find out what is actually happening here. The warning looks wrong, but there may be a reason for it. And if the compiler thinks this is an "assign" property, whether right or wrong, then your code will run into trouble. I'd check the original @interface for FBSessionAppSwitchingLoginStrategy, maybe methodName is mentioned there but in a different way.

Comment: It is the 3rd party library that gives me the warning. I don't think changing the code to remove the warning is a good approach. Because next 'pod install' call will clear all the fixes up.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the Facebook SDK is that the property is already defined in a parent class but with different attributes.

To solve the issue, try changing the parent definition in FBSessionLoginStrategy.h:53 to:

```
@property (copy, nonatomic, readonly) NSString *methodName;
```

That should solve your compile error.